# Auto start Nginx with non root user upon reboot

Tags: nginx

Hi I am trying to run auto start nginx upon reboot using nginx command line and i cannot make use of service as i need to run it as non root user. I have added an entry in crontab to call the script upon reboot but still it is not starting the service. However when i run the script normally, it works and just not working upon reboot.

### crontab -e

```
@reboot bash start_nginx.sh
```

### start_nginx.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/nginx -c /opt/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use systemd to auto-start nginx as a non-root user in Ubuntu 18.04 and nginx 1.14.  Explained below in 4 steps

1. Create User and Configure Permissions on Requisite Files
2. Configure New Default Ports
3. Set The User Daemon Will Start Under
4. Enable auto-start, Start the Service and Validate

#### Create User and Configure Permissions on Requisite Files

I found the guide [here](https://www.exratione.com/2014/03/running-nginx-as-a-non-root-user/) to be really helpful in orienting myself and configuring some of the harder-to-find nginx file permissions for the non-root user.

Regarding log permisions in `/var/log/nginx`
I handled this by adding the adm group to the user and `chmod`ing the permissions.

`$ sudo usermod -G <your group>,adm <your user>`
`$ sudo chmod 664 /var/log/nginx/*.log

Note that the adm group has access to log files throughout the system, and can run xconsole
to see the files owned by the adm group

```
$ sudo find / -group adm
```

also [see from ubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612751/what-is-the-difference-between-the-groups-adm-and-admin)

Please note that other scripts may try to change the permissions in /var/log, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794759/annoying-access-problem-on-var-log-nginx).  I added overrides with

`$ sudo dpkg-statoverride --add www-data adm 664 /var/log/nginx/error.log`

`$ sudo dpkg-statoverride --add www-data adm 664 /var/log/nginx/access.log`

#### Configure New Default Ports

We need to do this since non-root users cannot bind to ports < 1024
Modify listeners specified in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` so none are set < 1024

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

server {
    listen 8443;

}
```

And modify /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to change default listen from port 80

```
server {
    listen 8000 default_server;
    listen[::]:8000 default_server;
...
}
```

#### Set User Daemon Will Start Under (Edited)

Thanks to  Michael Hampton comment.  Note that I found the nginx service file in `/lib/systemd/system` from reading this [nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/), but instead of modifying anything in `/lib/systemd/system`, copy the file to `/etc/systemd/system` and modify there including two new lines under `[Service]` for the user and group you want to run nginx under

```
$ sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system
$ sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service

...
[Service]
User=<your user>
Group=<your user's group>
...
```

(note this nginx service file location may vary with different compilations of nginx)

#### Enable auto-start, Start the Service and Validate

```
$ sudo systemctl enable nginx
$ sudo systemctl start nginx
$ sudo systemctl status nginx
```

you will end up with something like this

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
nginx     1523  0.0  0.0 132216  1552 ?        Ss   06:12   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
nginx     1524  0.0  0.0 132628  5720 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     1525  0.0  0.0 132628  2428 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     1526  0.0  0.0 132628  2428 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     1527  0.0  0.0 132628  2428 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     1528  0.0  0.0 132628  2428 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     1529  0.0  0.0 132628  2428 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     1530  0.0  0.0 132628  2428 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     1531  0.0  0.0 132628  2428 ?        S    06:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Not even the master process is running as root (which I think is pretty cool!)

Comment: I edited your answer to replace the triple quotes for code blocks, check the "{ }" symbol while editing, it makes blocks of code easier to read than the triple quotes. You should use those on single lines or inside a sentence. Welcome to serverfault!!

Comment: DO NOT modify files in `/lib/systemd/system`. These are owned by the packages and your changes will be destroyed whenever the package is updated. You are meant to place your customizations in `/etc/systemd/system`, which is intended for local configuration. See the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

Comment: @MichaelHampton excellent point, learned something today. Thanks and updated

Comment: @Leo thank you for helping me with the formatting, much easier to read